# Loop through list of lists to plot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Trying to create a simple graph using a list of lists with year and value:

```
test_file = [[2000, 3.8], [2001, -2.4], [2002, 5.8], [2003, -10.5],
             [2004, 2.1], [2005, 2.1], [2006, 6.9], [2007, -3.9]]

for i in test_file:
    plot(test_file[i][0], test_file[i][1], marker="o",
         color="blue", markeredgecolor="black")
    axis([2000, 2007, -12, 10])
    show()
```

But I'm getting this error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you write `for i in test_file` what happens is that python iterates through the array `test_file` and in the first iteration takes the first item `[2000, 3.8]` and assigns `i` to this. This is not what you want. You should change your code into something like this:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, axis, show

test_file = [[2000, 3.8], [2001, -2.4], [2002, 5.8], [2003, -10.5], [2004, 2.1], [2005, 2.1], [2006, 6.9], [2007, -3.9]]
for year, value in test_file:
    plot(year, value, marker="o", color="blue", markeredgecolor="black")

axis([2000, 2007, -12, 10])
show()
```

> there is no line connecting the dots

In this case you need to reform your data a bit:

```
dates = [i[0] for i in test_file]
values = [i[1] for i in test_file]
plot(dates, values, '-o', color="blue", markeredgecolor="black")
```

> x-axis is 1-7 vs. 2000 - 2007

Yes, this is a little bit odd. One way to fix this is to turn the years which are now stored as integers into python `datetime.date` and run `autofmt_xdate()` on them, so the whole code reads:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot_date, axis, show, gcf
import datetime

test_file = [[2000, 3.8], [2001, -2.4], [2002, 5.8], [2003, -10.5], [2004, 2.1], [2005, 2.1], [2006, 6.9], [2007, -3.9]]

dates = [datetime.date(i[0], 1, 1) for i in test_file]
values = [i[1] for i in test_file]
plot_date(dates, values, "-o", color="blue", markeredgecolor="black")
gcf().autofmt_xdate()
show()
```

Comment: Same issue as below: x-axis is 1-7 vs. 2000 - 2007 and there are no lines connecting the dots.

Comment: with the first to lines (`dates=` and `values=`) you split them into two arrays. To connect the dots matplotlib needs to have the whole lists and not just single dots as you did before. Why that is I cannot say, this you'd need to ask in the matplotlib community

Comment: @user42760 I added some info on how to fix the x axis issue

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind importing numpy, converting the list to an array works pretty painlessly:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

test_file = [[2000, 3.8], [2001, -2.4], [2002, 5.8], [2003, -10.5], [2004, 2.1], [2005, 2.1], [2006, 6.9], [2007, -3.9]]
test_file = np.array(test_file)

plt.plot(test_file[:, 0], test_file[:, 1])
plt.show()
```

Comment: I will also try this.

Answer (score 0):

For line connecting dots, you need to specify plot data together in a list as below.

Bonus: I added x , y low and high value as variables instead of hardcoded in case data in `test_file` changes.

**EDIT**
Added `ScalerFormatter` to the code for `y-axis` to show actual y-axis values.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from  matplotlib import ticker
import math

test_file = [[2000, 3.8], [2001, -2.4], [2002, 5.8], [2003, -10.5], [2004, 2.1], [2005, 2.1], [2006, 6.9], [2007, -3.9]]
year   = [ i[0] for i in test_file]
value  = [ i[1] for i in test_file]
x_low  = min (year)
x_high = max(year)

y_low = float(math.floor(min(value)))
y_high = float(math.ceil(max(value)))

plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.title('Year and Value')


plt.plot(year ,value, marker="o", color="black", markeredgecolor="black")
plt.axis([x_low , x_high, y_low, y_high])

fmt=ticker.ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False)
fmt.set_scientific(False)
ax=plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)

plt.show()
```

**Default Plot**

[image: Default Plot]

**Plot with Actual Y-Axis Data**
[image: Formatted Plot]

Comment: Nice, but how do I get the x-axis to show the year (2000-2007) not the number (1-7). And the lines are blue and not black

Comment: See edits above. For black color for lines, Simply change `color="black"` in `plt.plot` and for plot to show actual y-axis data instead of default sequence. I added `Scalerformatter` method to set the default to off. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is great.  Also very helpful to see different approaches to the same issue.

Comment: If its helpful, up-voting would be encouraging.